# How to get value of data-subtext from Bootstrap Selectpicker?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using Bootstrap-Select in my project and I'm running into issues where I can retrieve the selected value but cannot figure out how to retrieve the sub-text of that value. Let's use this dropdown for an example:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="condimentPicker">
  <option data-subtext="Heinz">Ketchup</option>
  <option data-subtext="French's">Mustard</option>
  <option data-subtext="Hellmans">Mayo</option>
</select>
```

*Let's assume that Ketchup is selected*

In order to get the selected value of this dropdown, one would use `var selectedItem = $('#condimentPicker').val();`. In this case, `selectedItem = "Ketchup"`, however I would want `selectedItem = "Heinz"`. Any idea how to do this? I've search through the documentation and couldn't seem to find anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. `data-subtext` is just a custom attribute, so you can do the following to fetch that value:

```
var selectedItem = $("#condimentPicker option:selected").attr("data-subtext");
```